# Google Apps Script: Finding an element in a Column and returning the corresponding row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i want my program to search for an element in the first column of my google sheets and if the element is found , return the corresponding row .When i test this code, the element even if it is present shows that it isn't.

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AssaPoFPcazneN44EjE04fE99MxTaPZg5uMsO1Klh4o/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return finds(e,sheet);
}

function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AssaPoFPcazneN44EjE04fE99MxTaPZg5uMsO1Klh4o/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return finds(e,sheet);
  
}

function finds(e,sheet) {
  var records = {};
  var scannedData = e.parameter.sdata;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(r => r[0]); // -> get display Data as 1D array - Col A
  var  data = [];
  if(range.includes(scannedData)) { // use includes to see if scannedData is included in the array
       var row_scannedData = range.indexOf(scannedData);
       var result =  sheet.getRange(row_scannedData,1,1,4);  //fetches the entire row belonging to the result
       data.push(result);  //pushes the row in an array
       records.items = data; 
       var finalresult = JSON.stringify(records);
       return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Not Found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with a `TextFinder`.*

#### Code Sample:

**Assuming that there is only one cell in column A with your serach term:**

```
function searchColumnA(searchTerm) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var aColumn = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheeet.getLastRow());

  var tf = aColumn.createTextFinder(searchTerm).findAll(); 
  return tf[0].getRow();
}
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)